# Determining linear independence by inspection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given a question asking me to "determine by inspection whether the following vectors are linear independent." I know how to determine if vectors are independent by putting in row-echelon form and looking for free columns, but I don't know if determining by inspection is referring to a different method.

Is anyone familiar with this? Is there a different way to determine linear independence?

Comment: It probably means that you should be able to identify whether a vector is a linear combination of others in the list just by looking at them or doing simple algebra.

Comment: Without including the vectors, we can not help you.  Sometimes on is obviously a multiple of another:  E.g. $x+ y = 4;\;\;2x +2y = 8$.  But without showing us the problem statement, I don't think we can appropriately answer your question.

Comment: @amWhy I hear your point, but the reason why I did not include the vectors is that I was asking if the term meant anything particular. By your answer, I see it does not, and just means to look at the vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By inspection" literally means "by looking at it and seeing if there is anything obvious".

In the case of determining dependence of vectors, you know that the vectors are linearly dependent if you can write one of them as a linear combination of the others. So, for example, if you're given the vectors $x = (1, 0, 0)$, $y = (0, 1, 0)$ and $z = (4, 5, 0)$ then you can quickly see that $z = 4x + 5y$ and hence they are linearly dependent.

Similarly, if you see that the vectors are such that any attempt to combine them will result in non-zero values somewhere, then you can state that they are independent by inspection. Sometimes this might rely on knowing a few extra theorems - e.g. knowing that it takes $n$ linearly independent vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^n$, so if you can see that the group of vectors is able to span the space then they must be independent.